# How much energy does a lion contain?

Tags: zoology, literature

I was looking into the following problem:
[image: Who would win? 1 trillion lions or the sun?]
Obviously, the solution lies in how much energy either can output per unit of time.
The total energy output of the sun is $3.8×10^{26} \frac{J}{s}$.
The number of lions alone pales in comparison ($10^{12}$).

However, I'm now trying to figure out how many lions it would take to have an output equal to the sun, but I seem to be having a hard time finding good data.

What's the peak energy output of a lion per second (or where/how can I find such information)?

Comment: How do you define energy output? Its capacity to move an object, like horsepower? How much energy its cells produce? How much energy it would produce if completely combusted?

Comment: According tho [this websote](http://www.answers.com/Q/How_much_meat_does_a_lion_eat_in_a_day), a lion needs to eat from 5 to 7 kg of meat per day (with lots of variance from day to day going up to 50kg per meal). How much energy can a lion take up per kg of red meat? If someone find out this information we can easily answer the question by equating energy uptake and energy output (which totally makes sense for adults).

Comment: @MattDMo While it would be fair to compare combustion energy (since that's what the sun is doing), I would prefer the actual energy output of a lion itself in J/s (which is equivalent to Watts or ratio equivalent to horsepower, if you prefer that).

Comment: I assume that you mean "used" when you ay "output". Because of course there is tons of energy in matter that lions cannot access although this energy get through their body. Because input = output (when growth does not occur), there are two solutions available to us to answer this question: 1) How much do they eat and 2) How much carbon dioxide do they breath out

Comment: Peak energy output or average energy output? How long is this contest? Do we need to take into account rest/sleep/lifespan of lions? All important questions.

Comment: @Resonating To help the lions, I phrased the original question with peak output. But any data is appreciated, as I couldn't find anything reasonable myself.

Comment: Speaking of hypothetical scenarios - did you see the excellent and somewhat related [*A mole of moles*](https://what-if.xkcd.com/4/) from "what if?"?

Comment: Do you expect the lions to remain alive as they generate energy?  If not, do you assume infinite oxygen is available to burn them?  Is nuclear fission of the lions in scope?

Comment: If you burn the lions they're no longer lions, are they?

Comment: I think this would be a better fit for [physics.se]. I don't see how this is a question about biology. Fun question mind you, just off topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about physics, not biology. It just happens to use a living organism as an example.

Comment: @terdon Mind you, I originally asked this question on Physics.SE, but they said it was more fit for Biology.SE. So vote to migrate if you think it's appropriate, but I would say it isn't.

Comment: @Nit oh, damn. I can't vote to migrate (we have no path to Physics) only close. I think this is a cool question I just don't see anything biological about it. You could ask exactly the same thing replacing _lion_ with _stove_.

Comment: The interest doesn't seem to have to do with metabolism anymore but with physics. I therefore vote to close this question. The question might as well be flagged to be migrated to physics.SE

Comment: @terdon This is definitely borderline, but I think it should stay because of 3 reasons: 1) the quality of the answers, 2) as the answers show, the answer depends on how you interpret the energy output of lions and these discussion belong to biology, and 3) it's fun.

Comment: @fileunderwater I quite agree with points 1 and 2. However, the answers clearly push it into the realm of physics in my opinion. I don't see any biology in any of them. Which is not to say they are not fine answers, just not biological ones. I don't see how this can be answered by biology, it is pure physics.

Comment: @terdon The thing is that it was apparently deemed off-topic at PhysicsSE as well. It would be a shame and kind of sad to close such a fun/interesting Q at both sites, just because it is interdisciplinary/borderline at both. I think it should stay, just to define exactly where our line is drawn...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Wow, as an astrophysicist who has just logged into biology SE for the first time, I didn't think I'd have a question I could immediately answer.

You are correct about the Sun's output, so what about the lion.

If the lion is in its usual passive state, i.e. lying around as shown in your picture, then you would not go far wrong in treating them as black body radiators (well this will give you an upper limit, though the emissivity of human skin is quite high, so it should be a reasonable approximation.). To estimate a power I need a lion's temperature and its surface area.

According to [this site](http://www.felineconservation.org/feline_species/lion.htm) the body temperature of a lion is 311.33 Kelvin.

I found a calculator that used the DuBois formula for surface area (for humans) and put in 440 pounds and 7 feet 10 for the weight and "height" of a (male, adult) lion - this returned a surface area of $3.6\ m^2$ (about twice a, male human, so sounds roughly ok).

Now using the Stefan-Boltzmann formula $P = \sigma A T^4$, I get the power output of a "black body" lion to be about 2 kW.

Thus $10^{12}$ lions have a power output of $2\times 10^{15}\ W$, which is 11 orders of magnitude less than the Sun.

But now take the question at its most basic. Compared to the Sun, the lion is a pretty effective power generation unit. The Sun only generates $2\times 10^{-4}\ W/kg$, whereas a lion-based power source weighs in with a massive $10\ W/kg$!

EDIT: Note that the calculation just assumes the Lion can produce this kind of power output whatever environment it is in. In practice a Lion absorbs a large fraction of this power from its surroundings and its internal metabolism does not need (and probably cannot) supply 2kW. Thus the 2kW should be reduced to some extent, though I'm not sure a simplistic $T^4 - T_{\rm env}^{4}$ calculation can be correct, unless one of you biologists tells me that a Lion's metabolism shuts down once the ambient (African) temperature approaches 311K (I guess in a human a lot of it goes in evaporating sweat?) Whatever, the order of magnitude of the answer is unchanged.

Comment: This offers some interesting insight, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: But it probably wouldn't a useful power source, remember that those lions need 10W/kg worth of food.

Comment: You've accounted for the heat radiated by the lion, but not for the heat absorbed by radiation from its environment. So unless the lion is floating in deep space, you've dramatically overestimated its power output. Assuming an environment at 295K gives a much more modest power output of ~370W.

Comment: @David As lion is a warm blooded animal, regardless of external radiation, the surface temperature will more or less be constant

Comment: @CRags I doubt that a lion can hold its body temperature in a 0K environment. Unlike the sun, that can hold its body temperature in a 0K environment, the lion will just die.

Comment: I was not talking about surviving in 0 k

Comment: 311.48K, please :-)

Comment: @David I am well aware of that. I placed the lions and the Sun in a similar environment.

Comment: @RobJeffries I'd say it explicitly in the answer that you calculated how much power the body of a lion would emit if it was suddenly placed in 0K environment (before the body started cooling rapidly and the lion would die), not how much power output a lion can maintain in passive state.

Comment: @JiK Well, I would, but I'm still thinking about it. The intrinsic power output *is* that given by the Stefan-Boltzmann law. The environment simply affects in what way this energy was supplied to the Lion (either absorbed through its skin or eaten). To me it makes no sense (even for a crazy question) to subtract the power input from an external source (absorbed heat/radiation) in the same way that I do not subtract the power due to the rate at which the Lion is eating antelope. They both supply energy to the Lion, which it then radiates away at the approximate rate I've calculated. I'll edit.

Answer (score 5):

The sun will win until you have enough lions to form a star sized mass.

Assuming that your lions have an average mass of **200kg**, which is [probably pretty close](http://www.scribd.com/doc/15574755/Relative-Body-Mass-of-the-Lion-and-Tiger), 1 trillion lions has a mass of **2×10<sup>14</sup> *kg***, which is pretty close to the mass of [Remus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remus_%28moon%29), a moon around the asteroid Sylvia. The mass of the sun is about [**2×10<sup>30</sup> *kg***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun).

So your lions would have enough mass to become gravitationally crushed into an object, but probably not enough to become rounded. Once crushed they won't be able to carry out any metabolism.

Even if we considered the sum of 2 trillion individual lions the sun would still win because nuclear fusion completely outclasses chemical reactions in terms of energy released, and the mass of the sun is still much much much larger.

However, if we somehow converted the lions into energy by **E=mc<sup>2</sup>**, we get about **1.8×10<sup>31</sup> *J***. So if you managed that you could release more energy than the sun for a very short time.

Comment: I am not sure this was what the OP was after. He may have meant "energy consumption / metabolism" of a lion rather than the actual energy stored in its matter. But I missunderstand the OP's question.

Comment: @Remi.b It really doesn't matter, by the time you have enough lions for their normal metabolism to compete with the sun, you have more than enough mass to make a sun.

Comment: Ha ha yes I got this point. Well... but still I guess he would expect to know what is the ratio of the lion metabolism over the sun energy output. But the question might be better suited of worldbuilding.SE I guess

Comment: Relevant: https://what-if.xkcd.com/4/

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to work this from the angle of power the animals could produce for an extended (e.g. 1 hour) time. I'll assume that a lion produces power somewhere between that of a human and a horse, since the typical weight of a lion [(180 kg/400 lb-ish for males)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion) is between that of a human [(80 kg/180 lb-ish for males)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_weight) and a horse [(850 kg/1800 lb-ish for draft horses)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse#Size_and_measurement).

- Human: [100 W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_power)
- Horse: [746 W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horsepower) ("1 horsepower", or 746 W, is based off of how much work a draft horse can do for an extended period of time)
- Lion: 200 W?

So you would need 3.8×10<sup>26</sup>/200, or 1.9×10<sup>24</sup> lions. That's not a trillion, but about 2 trillion *trillion* lions. The exact amount of power produced won't change this too drastically, e.g. if our lions produce 800 W instead, it'd be 475 billion trillion lions.

Comment: Just a side note: this is an international website on science. Please use the SI system, i.e. kg instead of lb.

Comment: Just as another side note: the definition of a horsepower was taken off James Watt's marketing materials and is not a good guide to how much work a real draft horse can do even over a period of a few hours. Also: feel free to use lbs; this is an international site after all.